# Calculate "CO_FIPS" field based on "COUNTY" field

Tags: fields-attributes

I have several shapefiles with "COUNTY" already populated, I need to populate the "CO_FIPS" field based on the county.

BREVARD = 009, BROWARD = 011 etc..

Comment: I assume you want this for ArcMap?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include details of the GIS software you are using, please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the shapefile. Use this or just join it to your file based on the county names.
http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/26330-Where-can-I-find-a-shapefile-with-all-US-counties-and-FIPS-code-for-each

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArcMap, one way to do it would be to have a txt file set up like so:

```
County,CO_FIPS
BREVARD,009    
BROWARD,011
etc,etc
```

Then you would perform [Join data](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002q000000) and export the result to a shapefile.

Comment: @StuHamilton, and how do you figure that? For all we know, OP's shapefile could be point addresses and he wants a FIPS code associated with each point.

Comment: Hi Paul. He tells us he already has the names and he tells us they are in a shapefile. You are correct he could have hundreds of thousands of county names stored in points and the csv join would be more suitable. But if he has a list of polygons then it would be more work to type each name, each fips, and each comma than just typing them once in the editor. No hassle I should not have assumed polygon and will remove the comment.

Comment: @StuHamilton, too true! I hope I didn't come across as abrasive in my response. +1 as that link is darn useful. (I downloaded a copy.)

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the proper state and county to perform a join or look up for a field calculate. County fips are not unique by themselves. To make life easier for future projects I suggest creating a look up table that includes state, county, municipal fips (available from the census) and get the geographic names index from usgs. The geoid in the gnis table is the ANSI code. Your look up table should have both so you can cross reference many data sources. Using the census and the **[GNIS table](http://geonames.usgs.gov/domestic/download_data.htm)** as sources to make your look up should not have geometry since its just used to relate and join other info.

Comment: The table is in the shaepfile I sent him to do the join.